# Selecting HTML Dropdown Using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to scrape a website with a dropdown, pre-set to 20, with options 20, 50, and 100.

I'm trying to select 100, but setting .Value = "100" results in an error; .click just "opens" the dropdown so all options become visible; and .selectedIndex = x doesn't seem to do anything.  Is there another way to either set the dropdown to "100" or click the dropdown and select "100"?

The HTML:

```
<span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-active k-state-border-down" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-input" unselectable="on">20</span>
<span class="k-select" aria-label="select" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span>
<select style="display: none;" aria-label="20" data-role="dropdownlist">
    <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

My VBA:

```
If Not ieWebsite.document.getElementsByClassname("k-widget k-dropdown") Is Nothing Then
    Dim perPageOptions As Long
    perPageOptions = ieWebsite.document.getElementsByClassname("k-widget k-dropdown").Length
    For i = 0 To perPageOptions - 1
        On Error Resume Next
        For x = 0 To ieWebsite.document.getElementsByClassname("k-widget k-dropdown")(i).getElementsByTagName("option").Length - 1
            If ieWebsite.document.getElementsByClassname("k-widget k-dropdown")(i).getElementsByTagName("option")(x).Value = "100" Then
                ieWebsite.document.getElementsByClassname("k-widget k-dropdown")(i).getElementsByTagName("option")(x).Click 'JUST CLICKS THE DROPDOWN, NOT THE ACTUAL "100"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how yo can change it's value:

```
Dim selectList As Object
Set selectList = ieWebsite.document.querySelector("select[aria-label=""20""][data-role=""dropdownlist""]")

If Not selectList Is Nothing Then
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To selectList.Options.Length - 1
        If selectList.Options(i).Value = "50" Then
            selectList.selectedIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

I'm pretty sure that you'll have to make the list visisble before you can click the option:

```
Dim selectList As Object
Set selectList = ie.document.querySelector("select[aria-label=""20""][data-role=""dropdownlist""]")

If Not selectList Is Nothing Then
    selectList.Style.display = "inline-block"
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To selectList.Options.Length - 1
        If selectList.Options(i).Value = "50" Then
            selectList.Options(i).Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: This worked great!  All I had to add was change event to get the dropdown choice to refresh on the page.  I put this after setting the selectedIndex: Dim changeEvent As Object
                Set changeEvent = ieWebsite.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
                changeEvent.initEvent "change", True, False
                selectList.Options(i).dispatchEvent changeEvent
                While ieWebsite.Busy Or ieWebsite.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

Comment: Glaad to hear it!  Thanks for accepting my answer @jle